# Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a closed. Define $d(x)=\inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a closed. Define
$$d(x)=\inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|.$$ Prove that

1. $d(x)$ is a continuous function, and
2. $d(x)>0$ if and only if $x\not \in \mathcal{C}$.

Since $d(x)=\inf_{t\in\mathcal{C}}|x-t|$, then there exists $M\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x\leq M$. Recall that a function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $p\in \mathbb{R}$ if given $\epsilon>0$  there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-p|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(p)|<\epsilon$.

So let $|x-t|<\delta$. Then $$|d(x)-d(t)|=\left|\inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|-\inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|t-t| \right|=\left| \inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|-0\right|=\left| \inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|\right|= \inf_{t\in \mathcal{C}}|x-t|$$

And this is where I get stuck. Can I have some help.

Also can I get a hint on part 2?

Comment: There is non sense in "exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\le M$". On the other hand, you only proved that $|d(x)-d(t)|=d(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $t\in\mathcal{C}$, which is trivial.

Comment: Regarding part 2, if $x \not\in \mathcal{C}$, then $x \in \mathcal{C}^c$, which is an open set. Therefore $\mathcal{C}^c$ contains some neighborhood of $x$, say of radius $r > 0$. Show that $d(x)$ must be at least $r$.

Comment: @sinbadh So how should I proceed with part 1?

Comment: @Bungo For part 2, can i say each statement is an if and only if statement?

Comment: @UsernameUnknown: Certainly if $x \in \mathcal C$ then $d(x) = 0$, because $x$ itself is one of the $t$ values over which the infimum is taken. The only other possibility is $x \not\in \mathcal{C}$, in which case my sketched argument above will allow you to conclude that $d(x) > 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a. Fix an $x_0$. For any $y \in A$
$$\inf_{y \in A} |x-y|\leq |x-y| \leq |x_0-x|+|x_0-y|.$$

Since this holds for all $y \in A$, 
$$\inf_{y \in A} |x-y|\leq |x_0-x|+ \inf_{y \in A} |x_0-y|.$$
So
$$d(x)-d(x_0)\leq |x_0-x|.$$

By similar logic

$$d(x_0)-d(x)\leq |x_0-x|$$

So, for any $\epsilon>0$, if we let $\delta=\epsilon$, then $|x_0-x|<\delta$ implies that $|d(x_0)-d(x)|<\epsilon$, so $d(x)$ is continuous.

b. If x is in $A$ then it can't be that $d(x)>0$ because $|x-x|=0$. So, it remains to show that if x isn't in A, then $d(x)>0$.

We know that $A$ is closed, so we should look for a way to use that. Suppose $d(x)=0$, can you construct a sequence of points in A that converges to x? If you can, then you have a contradiction, since A being closed and $x$ being the limit of a sequence in $A$ implies $x \in A$.

Comment: Even better, since the inequality $|d(x)-d(y)| \leq |x-y|$ holds for all $x,y \in \mathbb R$, this implies that $d$ is uniformly continuous, and even Lipschitz continuous. If the OP has not yet encountered these notions, he/she will probably do so soon. Suffice it to say that these are especially well-behaved types of continuity which don't allow much bad behavior such as uncontrolled oscillation or unbounded "slopes".